# Laravel Ajax Store, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm starting to learn Laravel framework I just created an ajax function using online tutorials to save inputs in the database.

im getting **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** error

please help me to identify what did I miss and please explain to me what do we add URL in ajax function.

This is my Ajax Function

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
    url:"/blog",
    data: {
        '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), 
        'title': $('#title').val(),
        'body': $('#body').val()
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(resultData) { alert("Save Complete") }
});
```

This is my route file

```
Route::resource('/blogs', 'BlogsController');
```

this is my controller BlogsController.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Response;
use App\Blog;
use View;

class BlogsController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $blog = new Blog();
        $blog->title = $request->title;
        $blog->body = $request->body;
        $blog->save();
        return response()->json($blog);

    }    

`}
```

This is my Model Blog.php

```
    <?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Blog extends Model
{
    // IF our modal Name is Blog the Table name should be blogs or Else Define your Table
    //Table Name 
    protected $table = 'blogs';
    protected $fillable = ['title','body'];
}
```

Comment: You're missing a comma `,` after the `}` at the `'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')` line. Get a decent IDE and you won't have this problem anymore. I suggest PHPStorm, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: thanks but, still not working

Comment: Are you add `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` to your form?

Comment: @JacekBBudzynski avoid changing the content of someone's code when doing formatting. (you added a comma where there was none before)

Comment: @WesleyMurch Ok :(

Answer (score 1):

You missed a comma after

```js
   headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
```

and try full url path for ajax request.